# How to watch prop change in Vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm passing an array of image filepaths to a component.
I'm wondering what would be the best way to watch a prop change in Vue.js component, if I pass a different array?

I'm using bootstrap carousel, so wanna reset it to first image when array changes.
In order for simplicity I reduced code example to this:

```
Vue.component('my-images', {
  props: ['images'],

  template: `
    <section>
      <div v-for="(image, index) in images">
        {{index}} - <img :src="image"/>
      </div>
    </section>
  `
});
```

Comment: You can `watch` a prop just like if it were a data item.

Comment: A feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{count}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'test',
  props: ['count'],
  watch: {
    '$props':{
      handler: function (val, oldVal) { 
        console.log('watch', val)
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.count)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you expain this code a bit? i.e why/how it works?

Comment: Omg! This answer have just saved my few dozens lines of code. I was looking for a `componentWillReceiveProps` but for Vue.js. I had to watch every individual property in Vue watchers. But now I can watch them all in a single function. :) Thank you so much @binaryify

Answer (score 2):

You're good to go with this:

```
Vue.component('my-images', {
  props: ['images'],
  computed: {
    imagesComputed: function () {
      // just an example of processing `images` props
      return this.images.filter((each, index) => index > 0);
    }
  },
  template: `
    <section>
      <div v-for="(image, index) in imagesComputed">
        {{index}} - <img :src="image"/>
      </div>
    </section>
  `
});
```

Answer (score 1):

And example for typescript

```
  @Prop()
  options: any[];

  @Watch('options', {immediate: true})
  optionsChanged(newVal: any[]) {
    console.log('options changed ', newVal);
  }
```